# How to give equal spacing between letters of the word for the placeholder text in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField )textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString )string {
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textField.placeholder];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                             value:@(1.5)
                             range:NSMakeRange(0,textField.placeholder.length)];
    textField.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString;
    return YES;
}
```

I have tried this method but unfortunately, the method will work only something entered in the UITextField, But I want before entering anything in UITextField. The placeholder should have equal spacing between characters.
Thank you in advance

I want the output as the second UITextField shown in the image:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString ;

    attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self.firsttextfield.placeholder];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName
                         value:@(1.5)
                         range:NSMakeRange(0,self.firsttextfield.placeholder.length)];
    self.firsttextfield.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString;
    self.secondtexfield.attributedPlaceholder = attributedString;
}
```

I just kept the above lines in viewdidload rather than keeping them in the textfield function. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

**By default there is no property, you can do by this way.**

**method 1** :
    NSString *textToPrint=[NSString stringWithFormat:@“tehrsygghdBUY”];

```
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributeString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:textToPrint];


    [attributeString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                            value:[UIColor clearColor]
                            range:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];  // change it of spacing

    [attributeString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                            value:[UIColor LightgrayColor ]
                            range:NSMakeRange(3, [attributeString length]-3)];


    [_buyButtonView setAttributedTitle:attributeString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**method 2**     :

Sorry for textfiled, you have to give a uiview as super view of text field. and give transparent color to textfield. then frame 5 to 10 pints as origin x(frame of text field)